# C чего начать написание кода в yii

Tags: yii

Нужно написать часть сайта - оставление отзывов. С yii совсем не знаком. С чего начать?

Comment: А сам сайт на чем написан? а то вдруг там зенд крутиться :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. с рускоязычного сообщества [yiiframework.ru](http://yiiframework.ru/)
2. с [руководства](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/index) по фреймворку
3. с [создания блога](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/blog/ru/start.overview) по готовому сценарию

Если нет опыта в работе с другими MVC-фреймворками, есть смысл погуглить ключевик "MVC".

Answer (score 0):

А если опыт есть, то например посмотреть реализацию [feedback](http://yupe.ru/feedback/contact) на опен сорс [мини цмс на yii](http://yupe.ru/).